# How to take virtual machines state/back-up automatically?

Tags: virtualbox

My problem is,

> I want to take state/back-up of those 4 virtual machines(VMs)
>   automatically after every 2 days.

I am using Oracle virtual box(VB). I just want to know

**Is there any way or facility to achieve above thing?**

Answer (score 0):

Like pretty much everything else you can do with the VirtualBox GUI you can also do with the commandline tool `VBoxManage`.

It is part of your installation. The command you're most likely looking for is

`VBoxManage snapshot 'MyVM' take "Snapshot of MyVM on $(date)"`

```
snapshot                  <uuid|vmname>
                          take <name> [--description <desc>] [--live] |
                          delete <uuid|snapname> |
                          restore <uuid|snapname> |
                          restorecurrent |
                          edit <uuid|snapname>|--current
                               [--name <name>]
                               [--description <desc>] |
                          list [--details|--machinereadable]
                          showvminfo <uuid|snapname>
```

I tested it and it worked like a charm.

If you want to run it every 2 days, then `cron` would probably be your best option.

An entry like

```
0 0 */2 * * VBoxManage snapshot 'MyVM' take "Snapshot of MyVM on $(date)".
```

Inserted into your `crontab` will likely do the job (I did not test this). Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days).